# Is there a way to name a media query?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to name your media queries?

```
@media ("AddImageBorderQuery") {

    #Cats {
        border: 5px solid red;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

There's mention of something similar [here](https://css-tricks.com/naming-media-queries/).

My use case is different than defining classes and switching to them.

If you want more details I have completely different designs hidden behind different queries (single page application). Then in those designs I want to have specific states and I want to name the query so I can switch to those states. There can be large number of changes so I want to use nested query groups as a way to organize them.

I'm doing this manually now using a dictionary and code but naming media queries would simplify things.

```
@media ("page1") {
    @media ("AddImageBorderQuery") {

        #Cats {
            border: 5px solid red;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}

@media ("page2") {
    @media ("ShowContactForm") {

        #ContactForm {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}

window.showMediaQuery("ShowContactForm");
```

Comment: In scss yes, but in pure css no.

Comment: One approach to load media queries dynamically is by having a style tag with id, e.g. `<style id="app-dynamic-media-query">`, which content you can fill/replace later on the fly. You can access that style tag using `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @ChrisTapay Good idea. Now I wonder if it's possible to enable or disable a style sheet.

Comment: You cannot disable a stylesheet but you can just clear up the content of that `style` tag.

Comment: Would anything break if I did `@media (my_unique_id and min-width:99999px)` and then parse out the id?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to load media queries dynamically is by having a style tag with id, e.g. `<style id="app-dynamic-media-query">`, which content you can fill/replace later on the fly. You can access that style tag using `document.getElementById`.