# W3C, ECMAScript or professional recommendation on adding a property to an existing HTML class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727301/is-there-a-way-to-name-a-media-query) that asks if it's possible to name a media query. That so far has been unanswered.

So now I have thought about adding a `name` property to the media query in JavaScript.

My question is, is there any recommendation or reasons to not add my own custom properties onto an object?

There is a policy on SO that says not to ask questions that are debatable or something like that but this question is based in best practices and W3C recommendations. It is a valid question and I'll explain why.

People were adding their own custom attributes to HTML tags and eventually the W3C made a recommendation on it, "If you want to use your own attributes add a dash in the attribute name".

```
<input data-my-attribute="my attribute value"/>
```

The same thing happened for CSS variables and eventually they were added, "To create your own CSS variable add two dashes in front of the variable name".

```
.class {
   --my-css-variable-name: "my css value";
}
```

So there is a history in this sphere of questions.

***So are there any recommendations to adding your own properties onto existing classes or do you have any pros and cons about it?***

I know obviously, that one day the class may add a property of the same name to the class or that one day the class objects may not be dynamic.

Another example, I have a list of options in a select list and I would like to add a reference to an data object to it. Right now, HTML list options have one property.

I want to add a reference to the related object.

```
var list = document.getElementById("sizesList");

for (var i=0; i<sizeOptions.length; i++) {
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  let sizeOption = sizeOptions[i];
  let name = sizeOption.name;
  option.data = sizeOption;
  option.value = name;
  option.innerHTML = name;
  list.appendChild(option);
}
```

My instinct says adding a data property on an select Option is fine while adding a property to a mediaQuery object could break someday (but history shows properties added to tags or CSS became gradually accepted when using a specific syntax).

**Update**
Here is an example of adding a property to a HTML element:

[image]

Comment: How would you go about adding a `name` property to a media query, exactly?

Comment: I believe objects in JavaScripts are dynamic classes. That means that after you get a reference to it in JavaScript you can add a property onto it simply by setting it, `mediaQuery.name = "Query1";`. I suppose I could extend the classes I want to add properties to if that's possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Not a W3 policy, but definitely a professional: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @Bergi good find

Answer (score 1):

W3C has this to say about [custom data attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#attr-data):

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

So, yes, storing arbitrary data on an element is intended so long as you use the facilities provided for that.

---

W3C has this to say about [CSS variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#intro):

> This module introduces a family of custom author-defined properties known collectively as custom properties, which allow an author to assign arbitrary values to a property with an author-chosen name, and the var() function, which allow an author to then use those values in other properties elsewhere in the document. This makes it easier to read large files, as seemingly-arbitrary values now have informative names, and makes editing such files much easier and less error-prone, as one only has to change the value once, in the custom property, and the change will propagate to all uses of that variable automatically.

So CSS variables are meant to make styling a bit more convenient but not for storing arbitrary data. (Though this doesn't prevent you from doing so. If you can encode the data as a string, you can assign it to a CSS variable.)

---

As far as I can tell, `@media` is not really a collection, it's more of an `if/then` block for CSS. The CSS `@media` doesn't really have a manifestation in javascript.

`window.matchMedia()` can query the current media state but the object returned is generated anew on each call and isn't associated with any particular `@media` in the CSS.

`document.styleSheets` is tied to a collection of stylesheets as, essentially, text documents, not as some kind of CSS object structure.

While you could setup `:root` in each `@media` with a particular variable whose value is different for each `@media` section solely for the purpose of detecting which one is active, this seems like a maintenance problem waiting to happen.

Comment: I'm doing something like that with :root now. I have a set of custom CSS variables at the top level global class so adding :root to each media query might just work. I could then add the name to the media rule (see image posted) as a property (again the reason is pages are short termed) or use a dictionary to map the name with the query.

Comment: After reading http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ it's given enough reminders to avoid adding a property onto the object.